# How to Sort List in Ascending Order by Firebase Childs in Android

Tags: android, list, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                list = new ArrayList<>();
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 :dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    Model userdetails = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Model.class);
                    Model listdata = new Model();

                    String name = userdetails.getName();
                    String points = userdetails.getPoints();

                    listdata.setName(name);
                    listdata.setPoints(points);
                    list.add(listdata);

                }

                Adapter recyclerview = new Adapter(list, getActivity());
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutmanager);
                recycler.setItemAnimator( new DefaultItemAnimator());
                recycler.setAdapter(recyclerview);

            }
```

This is the code I'm using for retrieving data from firebase.

and below is the data.

[image]

I want to sort the data in ascending order but by the points.
Maximum the point will be on first.

Can Anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Model>() {
@Override
public int compare(Model lhs, Model rhs) {
    return lhs.getName().compareTo(rhs.getName());
}});
```

Comment: and I want to sort by points, not by name, otherwise, it's working

Comment: change  lhs.getPoints().compareTo(rhs.getPoints());

Comment: it's only comparing only first digit

Comment: i've modified some of it, but your answer helped me.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
public class Model implements Comparable<Model> {

@Override
    public int compareTo(@NonNull Model model) {
        String points= model.getPoints();
        return this.points.compareTo(model);
    }
}
```

and use `Collections.sort(list)` for array list.

**Note:**  Use integer for point value instead of string.

Answer (score 0):

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Model>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Model lhs, Model rhs) {
                        return Integer.parseInt(rhs.getPoints()) - Integer.parseInt(lhs.getPoints());
                    }});
```

The problem was it is in the string and I was comparing string, so I've converted it to an integer first and compared it.